# Coefficient of $x^k$ in the product of multiple polynomials

Tags: polynomials, products

It is well know that if we have two polynomials $f$ and $g$ such that $$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^nf_ix^i,\quad g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^mg_jx^j$$
then the coefficient of $x^s$ in the product $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ is exactly  $$\sum_{i+j=s}f_ig_j$$

But what about the product of $3$ polynomials? can we say, given another polynomial $$h(x)=\sum_{k=0}^rh_kx^k$$ the  coefficient of $x^s$ in the product $fgh$ is $$\sum_{i+j+k=s}f_ig_jh_k$$
I tried to prove it like this, the coefficient of $x^s$ in $(fg)\cdot h$ is $$\sum_{i+j+k=s}\left(\sum_{i+j=u}f_ig_j\right)h_k$$
But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Convolution of sums as you're doing is called "Cauchy product", have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Products_of_finitely_many_infinite_series

Comment: @PNT: If you like my answer, you can give it a green check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler if you write a polynomial in the form $f(x) = \sum_{i \ge 0} f_i x^i$ (with the underlying assumption that all $f_i$ are zero for $i > n$, but we only assume this $n$ exists, we don't need to explicit it).
$$
(f \cdot g \cdot h)(x) = \left(\sum_{i \ge 0} f_i x^i \right) \left(\sum_{j \ge 0} g_j x^j \right) \left(\sum_{k \ge 0} h_k x^k \right) = \sum_{i,j,k \ge 0} f_ig_jh_k x^{i+j+k} = \sum_{\ell \ge 0} \left( \underset{i+j+k=\ell}{\sum_{i,j,k \ge 0}} (f_ig_jh_k) \right) x^{\ell}.
$$
You can see how this easily generalizes to a product of $n$ factors.

Hope that helps,

Comment: The bulk of the proof, is hidden in the second equality, that distributivity for a product of two sums implies that formula for distributivity for the product of three or more sums. But yes, gathering coefficients of the same degree is simple after that.

Comment: @owl I don't think that was the OP's question. I understood that their problem was how to deal with the subscripts. Distributivity basically says that finite products and finite sums commute $(\prod_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J} = \sum_{j \in J} \prod_{i \in I})$ but the axiom only claims it (after stretching a bit) for $(a+b)(c+d) = ac + ad + bc + bd$. With a simple induction argument, it can be stretched to finite sums/products. You can make the products/sums "rectangular" by adding zeros like I did, letting the sums unbounded but with zeros at the tail.

Comment: Distributivity says $a(c+d)=ac+ab$, it is not even for two sums.

Comment: @owl That's the "after stretching a bit" part. If you wanted the base case for the induction, index the first sum over a singleton and the second over a two-set element. But to make the result more "square", you can assume all sums have the same number of elements and throw in some zeros.